# Position static gets broken

Tags: html, css

I have made a simple web page and it's working fine but, for some reason, if I want to change the position within the css from fixed to static, the web page gets completely broken.

I've tried to change the order in HTML but it seems not to work too...

The code where the mistake might be is here:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.v-header {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.container {
    max-width: 960px;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap video {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.header-overlay {
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #225470;
    opacity: 0.85;
}

.header-content {
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.header-content h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.header-content p {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

button {
    background: #34b3a0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.section {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.section-b {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

@media(max-width:960px) {
    .container {
        padding-right: 3rem;
        padding-left: 3rem;
    }
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: #005EFF;
}

.w3-content {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

For more detailed info and the rest of the code, here is a codepen.io link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzWvMP

Thanks,
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change nav only, changing to position absolute would do.

When static, it will go into container, when absolute, it will spread over.

Comment: Oh, yes! That's it! Thanks @cssBlaster21895